# Alternative patterns for different return types with same method call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-4.0

I would *like* to be able to implement the following three methods in my C# program:

```
public static WebResponse MakeAPICall(string url, string logonToken = null)
public static string MakeAPICall(string url, string logonToken = null)
public static XmlDocument MakeAPICall(string url, string logonToken = null)
```

Obviously, I can't do this because the calls are all ambiguous.  The idea here is that I'd like to be able to wrap the `WebResponse` function inside the `string` function and then that inside the `XmlDocument` function, so that I only have to manage the web request in one method, but call get the results in whatever form I need for the particular usage.

Is there any slick way to do this or am I just stuck making three uniquely named methods?  Maybe with an overload?

Comment: why not just give them different names? by the way they have different semantics, a WebResponse is a "live" object with an associated Stream, the request can still be running. string \ xmlDocument represent a completed response

Comment: What is the downside to naming them uniquely that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: No real downside.  Just looking for creative ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, can't override methods in C# on return types.

I too wish sometime the compiler supported this as well as attribute only overriding. Then in ASP.NET MCV one could have methods with the same name responsible for the GET and POST requests. Or in Web Api override a method based on the HTML, XML, JSON, etc. return type.